# Planks, supports, and a scale

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, statics

I've got two equal dimension planks with the same homogenous mass. They're placed next to each other like this (bird's eye view):

`[      ][      ]`

They're sitting on supports like this (side view):

`_______ _______
T       T      T`

If I place a scale on the middle `T` support with both ends of the planks sitting on the scale, can I get a reading of the weight of a single plank?

Comment: Hi. It doesn't matter whether it's literal homework, it's still a *homework style* question, as per the rules of this site. Can you show some of your own reasoning to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Cvpkryuq. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A proof that the weight is what you said.

Look at the free body diagram and assume the conditions outlined by BowlOfRed apply:

[image: Two planks.]

For each plank the sum of vertical forces is $W=2F$, so $F=W/2$.

Since as ***two*** of these forces act on the scales these will read the weight of a single plank.

The torque balance on each plank is $FL=WL/2$ ($L$ is the length of each plank) and with $F=W/2$ there's not net torque and no net rotation.

With no net force or torque acting on either plank they are stationary, as required.

Answer (score 0):

In the limit where

- All supports are exactly the same height
- All supports are perfectly level
- The planks are perfectly flat
- The material has the same amount of overlap on the inside and outside supports

then you would be measuring the weight of 1 plank and the center support under the center scale.

If we assume that the planks are symmetrically supported, perfectly level, and have uniform mass distribution, then the support points will be the same distance from the center of mass.  As it is not rotating, the torques are equal.  Since the distance and torques are equal, the forces are equal.  So in this situation, half of the weight of each plank is supported on each end.  This means the center support is holding two half-weights, or the weight of one plank.

But in the real world, this will be difficult to achieve.  If the supports aren't flat and level (or the planks are not), then the contact points for the planks can shift.  This shift changes the lever arm and shifts the weight from one side to another.

Comment: I took three semesters of physics when I was younger. I think I could handle a proof if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: A proof that the weight is what I said when everything is equal, or the reason that the weight is different when things are unequal?

Comment: A proof that the weight is what you said.